# Existence of general cyclic pseudorandom generator of a fixed length

Tags: number-theory

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806959/reversible-1-limit-1-limit-function) on StackExchange and was refered here. So here it goes.

Is there a general solution to the problem:

Given the **limit**, find a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ with the following properties:

$a,b$,limit - natural numbers

For every $a$ in domain $0 < a < $ limit
the following should hold:

$f(a) = b$,  $0 < b <$ limit

$g(b) = a$

$a<>b$

The functions $f,g$ should not be linear either in whole, or in segments (like for example, reordering digits and offseting them).

Comment: What is the meaning of $a<>b$?

Comment: a is not equal to b. When I think of it, it is redundant (f,g being non-linear covers that condition).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\log(1+x)\qquad g(x)=\mathrm e^x-1$$